# Should you use "the" when writing uncountable nationality adjectives?

Tags: pronouns, nouns

Example sentence:

> (The) Japanese have been doing business with (the) Chinese for a very long time.

(Maybe using "the" is a bit offensive?)

Comment: If you had to add a noun after "Japanese" or "Chinese", what would it be?

Answer (score 2):

#### There is nothing intrinsically offensive about the following noun phrases: *the Japanese, the Chinese, the Portuguese, the Nepalese, etc.*

#### It's not idiomatic (or natural) to say *a Japanese, a Chinese, a Portuguese, a Nepalese, etc.* to refer to a single Japanese / Chinese / Portuguese / Nepalese / etc. person. These expressions are also not offensive; they are simply not used in English. However, *a Japanese / Chinese / Portuguese / Nepalese / etc. person/student/man/woman/child* all sound idiomatic (natural).

---

[*Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/) has the following entries:

> #### [the Chinese](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-chinese)
>
> people from China
>
> ---
>
> #### [the Japanese](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-japanese)
>
> people from Japan

So, these simply mean people from China and Japan, respectively.

The following sentence,

> 1. **The Japanese** have been doing business with **the Chinese** for a very long time.

is completely grammatical and idiomatic. *Japanese* and *Chinese* are adjectives. They're heads of their respective noun phrases. *Did you say **noun** phrases?* Yes, it's an odd phenomenon, because usually you have *nouns* heading *noun* phrases (e.g., in *a pretty girl*, *girl* is a noun, and functions as head of that noun phrase), but some adjectives can be used this way as well; namely, *poor*, *rich*, *free*, *gifted*, *Chinese*, *Japanese*, etc.

This special construction where an adjective functions as **fused modifier-head** has a couple of interesting properties. One such property is that no other determiner other than *the* is permitted; for example, ***a*** poor / Chinese / gifted wouldn't be grammatical. Another property (with few exceptions) is that the entire noun phrase is plural, which means you can't say *the rich / Japanese / free **has** something*.

---

> 2. **Japanese** have been doing business with **Chinese** for a very long time.

Once again, *Japanese* and *Chinese* are adjectives which normally function as attributive modifiers in these positions in a sentence – except there aren't any nouns they might modify: *Japanese **companies** have been doing business with Chinese **companies** for a very long time* would be okay because now there are nouns in that sentence which these adjectives modify.

Moreover, these adjectives aren't functioning as fused modifier-heads either. We can see that because *the* isn't present in these supposed noun phrases.

Sentence 2 is therefore ungrammatical.

Comment: I agree with the answer but why bother reposting the wrong one and analyzing it? Also, in  your second paragraph, you say A Japanese is not natural, then you say it is. Perhaps you ***forgot***: A Japanese person, man, woman, child, citizen, etc? Right?

Comment: @Lambie Oh, I see what you mean. Sorry, I edited that part so many times because I wasn't sure whether to use forward slashes or what, and then I somehow lost the crucial word there.

Comment: No worries. It happens to me all the time.

Answer (score -1):

I can think of two things.

Firstly, if you want to address the people of Japan in a *general way,* you may omit the article.

> Japanese love sports.

But, if you are specific about those people, you put *the.*

> The Japanese did better in the finals.

Secondly, words like Russians and Germans don't need *'the'* because they are undoubtedly *nouns.* On the other hand, *French* and *English* are nouns and adjectives (French dishes). So, to distinguish between them, the definite article is needed.

Nevertheless, in your case, the *context* is clear as you want to address them *in general,* hence, I'd not put any article.

> Japanese have been doing business with Chinese for a very long time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By "people" you mean all Japanese/Chinese people, or a group of them?

Comment: I can't agree with your conclusion; though I'm no grammarian so it's just "it sounds wrong to me". 'The' ought to be there in all cases except the 2 language adj. references, for me.

Comment: @alex people, the citizens of the countries.

Comment: @Tetsujin at least *[Indian newspapers](https://indianexpress.com/article/trending/trending-globally/believe-it-or-not-japanese-man-was-fined-for-taking-lunch-break-3-minutes-early-5229064/)* put [that way](https://food.ndtv.com/food-drinks/this-peculiar-japanese-egg-video-will-compel-you-to-watch-it-again-and-again-1770969). And, note that, I'm not *completely against* the article.

Comment: Neither of those examples supports your theory or disagrees with mine. The newspaper is using 'headline-ese' & the other I don't see any relation to the question, except that it does use a definite article, 'this'.

Comment: What headlines..check the beginning @tetsujin and we all know once you introduce a subject, you use definite article. I found a pen, the pen was red. that's why the body has the definite article. Again, I'm not against that.

Comment: Hmm... yes. Looks horrible.